# Symfony2 entity field type (many-to-many form) wrapped in <li>s

Tags: symfony

I have a form `buildForm()` function that looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{   
    $builder->add('interestingSports', 'entity', array(
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'property' => 'name',
        'class'    => 'Foo\MyBundle\Entity\Sport',
    )); 
}
```

This works fine, except the form just plops out a bunch of checkboxes with no `<li>`s or anything around them, and I want `<li>`s.

Does Symfony have a way for me to put each checkbox in an `<li>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best and easiest way to display your checkboxes surrounded by `<li>` tags is to [customize your form rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html) by displaying fields individually,

```
{# Any other form field #}
{{ form_widget(form.otherField) }}
{{ form_widget(form.otherField) }}
{# ... #}
{# Your checkboxes surrounded by <li> tags #}
{% for field in form.interestingSports %}
   <li>
     {{ form_label(field) }}
     {{ form_widget(field) }}
   </li>
{% endfor %}
{# Render all fields that have not yet been rendered #}
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Comment: You're welcome, and If you want to customize a specific field type rendering at different levels of your application (it depends on your needs) take a closer look at the [form theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming) section of the documentation.