# Dynamically setting class attribute to a symfony2 choice list generated from an entity in FormBuilder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, checkbox, formbuilder

I'm wondering how can I dynamically set the HTML class attribute to checkbox elements using FormBuilder in Symfony2.
I'm using an element generated by an entity :

```
add('myEntity', 'entity', array(
   'class' => 'MyBundle:myEntity',
   'property'      => 'label',
   'multiple'      => true,
   'expanded'      => true,
))
```

This only sets the id of the checkboxes according to this template : **[form_name]_[class_name]_[id]** (for example acme_my_form_my_entity_5)

I want to know if I can also set the class attribute with these values : **[form_name][class_name][label]**. Label is another field in the entity.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Is possible, but you will need to read the Docs!

- [Form Customization](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

If you are lazy and do not want to read them, then just search google using "custom checkboxes symfony" and you will come back to Stackoverflow, where there are many other examples [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568515/symfony2-how-to-render-checkboxes). Replying with code will be just a copy of another examples, so you better build your own customized one and paste it as your own solution.

If you want an easy solution, keep in mind you can to something like this directly in your Twig template:

```
{{ form_widget(form.myEntity, { 'attr': {'class': **Your_dinamic_class_value**} }) }}
```

Comment: Well ... You were too lazy assuming that I was just lazy. I assure you I am totally aware of the two suggestions you made, but it couldn't solve my problem.

Either I wasn't clear enough (if so, sorry about that english is not my mother tongue) or you didn't understand what I ment. I'll try to clarrify that :

When I the code you provided, I get this :

`<div id="acme_my_form_my_entity" class="Your_dinamic_class_value">
  <input type="checkbox" id="acme_my_form_my_entity_5" name="fos_user_registration_form[jobs][]" value="5">
...
</div>`

Comment: Only the containing div gets the _static_ class attribute we provided in the form_widget call. What I want is that each input elements get a different class attribute, for example 

`<input type="checkbox" ... class="acme_my_form_my_entity_**labelA**"><input type="checkbox" ... class="acme_my_form_my_entity_**labelB**">`.

And I don't see how I could do this by not overriding all of the div_form_layout.html.twig !