# Symfony2 : Add specific class to option in form builder

Tags: php, css, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I have a simple question : Can we pass css class to options in form_builder ? I explain :

I have a field and I passed the `$options`values like this

```
$builder
    ->add('motif', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $options['data']['myoptions'],
        'multiple' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'expanded' => false,
    ));
```

On my template this code look like a simple select list like this

```
<select name="exempleselect">
    <option value="1">value 1</option> 
    <option value="2">value 2</option>
    <option value="3">value 3</option>
</select>
```

Can we pass css class to get my list like this ?

```
<select name="exempleselect">
    <option class="value1" value="1">value 1</option> 
    <option class="value2" value="2">value 2</option>
    <option class="value3" value="3">value 3</option>
</select>
```

Thanks

Comment: all you need is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568515/symfony2-how-to-render-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$builder
->add('motif', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $options['data']['myoptions'],
    'multiple' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'expanded' => false,
    'attr' => array('class' => 'your class',
                     OR
                    'style' => 'width:100px; ...'
));
```